# Using 2 submit button in a same row with different function in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, system.reflection

In my View, I used 2 submit button, Search and Reset

```
    <p>
        Name: @Html.TextBox("searcher", (string) ViewBag.searchValue) 
                <input type="submit" value="Search" /><input type="submit" name="Reset" value="Default" />
    </p>
```

And in Controller, I assign to the **Default** button to clear all searchValue and Parameter.

```
        [HttpPost, HttpParamAction]
        public ActionResult Reset()
        {
            ViewBag.searchValue = "";
            Index("", "", "");
            return View();
        }
```

However, the result instead of clear all parameter and searchValue, **Default** button now just act like another **Searching** button. I have imported **System.Reflection** in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try following way,

Model: Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller: HomeController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveProduct(Product obj)
 {
     ViewBag.Message = "Product saved successfully!";
     return View("Index", obj);
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CancelProduct(Product obj)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "The operation was cancelled!";
    return View("Index", obj);
}
```

View: index.cshtml

```
@model ViewBag_array.Models.Product

<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
@Html.DisplayForModel()

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" formaction="SaveProduct" formmethod="post" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" formaction="CancelProduct" formmethod="post" />
}
```

This way you get a cleaner separation of the concerns and the code is more readable.

Comment: This way, the result will return something like **./Home/CancelProduct** instead of just **./Home**, this way, any interaction with the page after I pressed become invalid. It seem remove the **formaction**, do what I needed. My end code somewhat look like this: **Controller**: `return View(Index)` - **Index.cshtml**: `<input type="submit" name="Reset" value="Default" formmethod="post"/>`

Comment: My mistake...I edited the above code...I use return View(Index, obj) to send data to view if needed. You can be modified according to your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

An input button will do the trick.

```
<input type="button"
         name="Reset" value="Default"
         onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Reset", "Controller") %>'" />
```

Comment: can you explain a bit about 
`<%: Url.Action("Reset", "Controller") %>` ?
my controller named **MembersController.cs**